# Word for "excessively sweet" with negative connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

Which word can describe a product or dish which is so sweet that it is almost impossible to eat or to enjoy it? For example "this jam is ___ , i can't even eat it".

I found "[sugary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sugary)" and "honeyed" (linked in the "sugary" entry) but I think they are rather postive than negative.

Comment: Please edit your question to include two things so that it can be reopened. First, please include a couple possible sentences illustrating how you would use this term, leaving a blank `________` where it would go. Second, please **present your research** into this by showing us which possible terms you discovered but discarded, and tell us why you found each of those inappropriate for your purposes.  I encourage you to take our [tour].

Comment: [_cloying_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cloying) 
, but the Q is closed and not accepting answers...

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks for being considerate. I won't forget that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***cloying***

> Excessively sweet, rich, or sentimental, especially to a disgusting or sickening degree.

[Lexico](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=4RdRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA610&dq=cloying&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQjPOTrJfuAhXPxVkKHUvdBecQ6AEwA3oECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=cloying&f=false)

...as in "This jam is ***cloyingly sweet***."

The word can also be used to describe perfumes, overly-sentimental movies, etc.

The usage goes back to at least the Elizabethan times

> We sicken to shun sickness when we purge, 
> Even so, being full of your ne'er ***cloying sweetness***, 
> To bitter sauces did I frame my feeding...

[William Shakespeare](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=4RdRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA610&dq=cloying&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQjPOTrJfuAhXPxVkKHUvdBecQ6AEwA3oECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=cloying&f=false)

Answer (score 12):

Although other senses get in the way, one near-literal sense of **saccharine** fits:

> **saccharine** [adjective]
>
> 2: overly or sickishly sweet
>
> - [a] saccharine flavor

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saccharine)]

The default use of the adjective is the metaphorical sense, putting on a pretence of friendliness. The *sickly-sweet flavour* sense would probably be mainly found in literature, and not in a predicative usage.

"This dessert is/tastes saccharine" isn't idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

[sickly-sweet](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sickly-sweet)

> Excessively or unpleasantly sweet.

Comment: Just what I was about to put down.

Answer (score 0):

***[Sugary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sugary)*** may convey the idea of something that is too sweet.

> Sugary food or drink contains a lot of sugar.

> - Sugary canned drinks rot your teeth.

(Collins dictionary)

> exaggeratedly sweet

> cloyingly sweet

[(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sugary)

Comment: Would "sugary song/movie" have a negative or a positive assessment?

Comment: @Drossel - a negative one. Unless you like movies/songs that are too sentimental.

Comment: @Drossel - if you click on the M-W link you will see that the definition is “cloyingly sweet.”

Comment: Sugary just doesn’t have any negative implications for me. “Sugary treats” sound great.  In fact you can find people with businesses named “Sugary treats”  I also don’t think the M-W dictionary defs reflect the true usage of the word.  If there’s too much sugar then it’s ***too sugary*** not just *sugary*.

Answer (score 0):

- The jam is "too" sweet to eat.

I think it conveys the desired effect
."–too...to "construction.